# How to put image in another window in tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-3.7

I want to put an image in the second window using `tkinter`, in the first window the code works good, but the second window shows nothing.

In this part I import necessary modules:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Frame, Label, PhotoImage, Button
from PIL import  Image
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
```

Then create the principal window:

```
raiz = Tk()
raiz.title("ventana")
```

Then I create the frame and put the image in the frame:

```
 miFrame = Frame()
 miFrame.pack()
 miFrame.config(width="1400", heigh=("1200"))

 fondo=tk.PhotoImage(file="fondoF.png")
 fondo=fondo.subsample(1,1)
 label=tk.Label(miFrame,image=fondo)
 label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)
```

Then a button that will call the second window function:

```
 btn3 = Button(raiz, text="boton")
 btn3.place(x=500, y=500)
 btn3.config(command=abrirventana2)
```

Here we have the function which opens the second window and here (I guess) is where I want to put the image.

This part also has two buttons named `mih` which does nothing in the meantime and `ok` which calls the function to close the second window:

```
def abrirventana2():
 raiz.deiconify()
 ventana2=tk.Toplevel()
 ventana2.geometry('500x500')
 ventana2.title("ventana2")
 ventana2.configure(background="white")
 fondov=tk.PhotoImage(file="xxx.gif")
 label1=tk.Label(ventana2,image=fondov)
 label1.place(x=50,y=50,relwidth=5.0,relheight=5.0)
 mensaje=tk.Label(ventana2,text="funciona")
 mensaje.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
 boton1=tk.Button(ventana2,text='mih')
 boton1.pack(side=tk.TOP)
 boton2=tk.Button(ventana2,text='ok',command=ventana2.destroy)
 boton2.pack(side=tk.TOP)
```

Function to close the second window:

```
def cerrarventana2():
    ventana.destroy()
```

I use the mainloop to keep the window open

```
 raiz.mainloop()
```

Note: I had already tried creating a frame in the second window, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for my previously incorrect answer.
The reason the image is not showing is due to the fact that you did not create a reference to it. If you don't create a **reference**, the image is garbage collected, which doesn't remove it, but in a sense just renders a blank placeholder on the GUI.

In order to display the image correctly you need to add a reference to the image within the code that displays the image.
You therefore now have:

`fondov=tk.PhotoImage(file="giphy.gif")
 label1=tk.Label(ventana2,image=fondov)
 label1.image = fondov
 label1.pack()`

> (`label1.image = fondov` is the reference)

Sorry for the confusion there. This should work.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help, i didnt notice the part "label1.pack" without the "()", but it is not the problem.:c , also i did what u said about ".place" and ".pack" but the issue persist :c

Comment: Apologies, my previous answer was actually incorrect. I had a play around and sorted the issue. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, now is working really well. I'm new here, how can i give you points or something like that? :v

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct :) Would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm new to python and I've been playing with tkinter to do GUI, I hope I can count on you if I have another problem. i saw in your profile that your are doing a GUI, are yo using tkinter or an another library?

Comment: Only TkInter at the minute. I've not had much experience with any other GUI kits.

Comment: @Camilo Andres Perez Sanchez. Please mark my answer as correct if it solved your issues. It'll make the solution clearer to others with the same problem.